# The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int

Tags: java, int, undefined, operator-keyword

I have little problem with my Java code. I'm using code below but Eclipse always prompting same message "The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int".

Anyone having an idea about it? Please help. Thank you so much;

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int pozitif = 0;
        int negatif = 0;
        int cevap;

        String Soru1 = "Soru1";
        String Soru2 = "Soru2";
        String Soru3 = "Soru3";
        String Soru4 = "Soru4";
        String Soru5 = "Soru5";
        String Soru6 = "Soru6";

        String Soru[] = {Soru1,Soru2,Soru3,Soru4,Soru5,Soru6};

        for(int i = 0; i < Soru.length; i++){

            cevap = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(i + 1 + ". soru " + Soru[i]));
            if(cevap == 1){
                pozitif++;
            }if(cevap == 0){
                negatif++;
            }if(cevap != (1 || 0)){  // !!! Problem is here!!!
                Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(i + 1 + ". soru " + Soru[i] + "Lütfen (1) ve (0) giriniz!!!"));
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Pozitif: " + pozitif);
        System.out.println("Negatif: " + negatif);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think result of `1 || 0` should be? What operation `||` represents here?

Comment: If users answer wont be "1 or 0" from keyboard Same message will prompt again with a string( Please answer with(1) or (0)) ;

Comment: `||` means "or", so for that to work, both sides of the `||` *must be boolean*. Neither `1` nor `0` are boolean, so `(1 || 0)` fails.

Comment: @user3238467 Then you can create your condition as mc10 suggested in his answer. You can also use something like `if (!Arrays.asList(1, 0).contains(cevap))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `else` statement is what you need:

```
if (cevap == 1){
    pozitif++;
} else if (cevap == 0) {
    negatif++;
} else {
    Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(i + 1 + ". soru " + Soru[i] + "Lütfen (1) ve (0) giriniz!!!"));
}
```

This does what you want: when `cevap` is not equal to `1` or `0`, run what's in the `else` block. If you did not want to use an `else` block (and I'm not sure why you wouldn't), you can use the more verbose `(cevap != 1 && cevap != 0)`.

Comment: I tried both of them "(cevap != 1 && cevap != 0) - (else)"; (cevap != 1 && cevap != 0) worked(Thank you so much). I tried to use "else" but it prompted altarnate massege in all conditions. Thanks for "&&" advice.

Comment: The above code should work. If you want to use the more verbose condition, replace `else` with `else if (cevap != 1 && cevap != 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare `cevap` to two different numbers. You have to do it like this:

```
if (cevap != 1 && cevap != 0)
```

So basically it's "if cevap is not equal to 1 and cevap is not equal to 0".

Comment: He can't just write `else`.  He needs to turn the middle block into an `else if` if he wants to use `else`.

Comment: Didn't see he didn't do that, changed it