# The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-logic

I have little problem with my Java code. I am using Dr.Java and it is giving me the error message that "The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int". If anyone could please

```
import java.util. Scanner;
public class Days

{ public static void main( String [] args)
  { Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.print(" What month is it  ? " );
    int month= in.nextInt();
    System.out.print( " What day is it " );
    int day = in.nextInt( );




    **if( month == 1 || 2 || 3 )**
    {  System.out.print( " Winter" ) ;
    }
    else 
    {
      System.out.print( " Fall " ) ;
    }


}
}
```

Comment: The way you wrote it is syntactically incorrect.  See SURESH ATTA for correctness

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369530/the-operator-is-undefined-for-the-argument-types-int-int?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
month == 1 || 2 || 3
```

first part of expression would return `boolean` and you cannot `||` `boolean` and `int`

change it to

```
if( month == 1 || month == 2 || month == 3 )
```

or

```
if( month >= 1 &&  month <= 3 )
```

considering `month` is `int`

Answer (score 10):

Your syntax is wrong. Correct syntax is

```
if( month == 1 || month == 2 || month ==3 ) { .... }
```